# TRichEdit finding protected text

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, richedit, delphi-4

I am working on a TRichEdit (Delphi XE2).

Is there any way i can check whether the richedit textbox contains protected text or not?  Also the starting position of that protected text without iterating through the complete text.

Currently i am using the code below

```
source.SelStart := charNo; //source is richedit name and charno is the                     
                        //iterating loop 
source.SelLength := 1;
if (source.SelAttributes.Protected) then
```

The above code takes a lot of time for execution when the text is large.

This used to work fine in delphi 4

Can someone please tell why is the same code talking more time in delphi XE2 and less time in Delphi 4 also the proper way to do this in Delphi XE2?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to search for text attributes.  Iterating the individual characters and querying their attributes is the only option.

To speed up the code, you can:

1. use the [`EM_SETSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661.aspx) or [`EM_EXSETSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788007.aspx) window message instead of setting the `SelStart` and `SelLength` properties individually.
2. Use the [`EM_SETEVENTMASK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774238.aspx) window message to turn off the RichEdit's internal notifications (such as `EN_HSCROLL`, `EN_VSCROLL`, and `EN_SELCHANGE`) while you are iterating.
3. You might also consider using the [`WM_SETREDRAW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219.aspx) window message to disable the RichEdit from repainting while you are iterating.